# Exit Behavior in packages of advance UI

Tags: installshield, installshield-2015

I am using InstallShield 2015.

I have created an Advance UI project which contains multiple packages, which install one by one.

I need to check a condition after a package installation and prompt a message whether to abort the installation or not.

I saw an option in packages -> Common -> Install -> Exit Behavior -> Ask Whether to continue the setup.

But how can I make a conditional Exit Behavior?

Eg: I need to check a condition like file exists or not, if Exists -> Continue the Setup. Else -> Ask Whether to continue the setup.

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

With my knowledge, I believe there is no option available to meet this requirement in Advanced UI project. But in suite project, you can add a event with installscript function (where u can call abort method). Then you can bind the action in package configured stage with the necessary conditions.

[image]